# Why do we need to restart an Express server to see changes on the browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Why do I have to restart my Express server every time I make a change in my Express code ? I want to know the internal working of express and is it same with other server side frameworks as well like Ruby on Rails?

Comment: When you run NodeJS app, code is being loaded into ram memory. The only solution is restart app manually or use automate restarting like nodemon

Comment: When running locally, you can use tools for restarting automatically while developing, to make this easier. For example `nodemon`.

Answer (score 6):

Your server code is complied by your computer. When you restart your server the code is recompiled to accommodate the new changes. All server codes run on the computer and once changed have to be recompiled and run.

Comment: yes, whenever you do node filename.js , its similar to executing python abc.py

Comment: one should mention JIT here

Comment: According to my knowledge V8 converts ( interprets donno the exact wordings) directly into machine code which is then compiled by JIT. (Wordings may not be correct)